# Unbinding and rebinding a Linux device driver

Tags: linux, audio, driver

I'm currently fighting with a buggy hardware device under Linux. The device provides a series of interface endpoints. From what I can tell if I can configure the alternateSetting of a couple of these endpoints to their other modes then the device should behave properly. This functionality appears to be in the usb_modeswitch tool, but it can't act directly on a device as long as a driver is bound to the device.

Dumping the usb device information via `usb-devices` contains the following list of interfaces.

```
C:  #Ifs= 6 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 4 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 5 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid
```

by navigating into /sys/bus/usb/drivers/snd-usb-audio I can unbind the various devices individually by calling `echo -n "1-10:1.#" > unbind`.

```
C:  #Ifs= 6 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#= 4 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 5 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid
```

Once I do this though, I expect to be able to call `echo -n "1-10:1.#" > bind` to rebind the driver, but trying this returns the error.

```
bash: echo: write error: No such device
```

Firstly, what is the proper way to rebind this device interface to the snd-usb-audio driver?

**EDIT**

Contents of /sys/bus/usb/devices after the unbind command.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan  1 18:00 1-10 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan  1 18:00 1-10:1.0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan  1 18:00 1-10:1.1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan  1 18:00 1-10:1.2 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan  1 18:00 1-10:1.3 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan  1 18:00 1-10:1.4 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan  1 18:00 1-10:1.5 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.5
```

On that note, the bind command still produces a `No such device` er using the full path of the device as

```
echo -n "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-10/1-10:1.4" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/snd-usb-audio/bind
```

as well as using the symlink from the sysfs usb directory

```
echo -n "/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-10:1.4" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/snd-usb-audio/bind
```

Comment: add to your question output of issuing    `ls -l /sys/bus/usb/devices`   also assure you are using matching double quote pairs ... in your echo command its missing

Comment: you are correct on the double quotes, I've updated to reflect that. And the contents related to the 1-10 device included.

Comment: Hey @Luke, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I never did. I became convinced my specific higher level problem was caused by a separate kernel bug and went digging around in that direction instead.